# How to make sortable element trigger sort by its upper border or header (and not rely on the mouse location)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I implemented a sortable dashboard with widgets based on the jQuery sortable portlets example ,

Some of the widgets are bigger then others (their height is bigger) , and when I drag them between columns (while initially clicking on their center) and expecting the placeholder to appear I need to drag the big widget center (wheres the mouse points) so that the mouse will be located right beneath the target widget (mean while the dragged widget upper boundary is way above the target widget)

**Here a : [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/3LKj4/)**

Click on the vertical center of big widget and try to place it beneath other widget, If you were doing it by clicking the header of the big widget it would have been much easier to drag it beneath the other widget (the place holder would have appeared right away)

One more thing, for an unknown reason in my real web app (and not in the jsfiffle example) even when i drag the big widget from its header its acts as I was holding the widget from its vertical center... any Ideas why?

B.T.W : I don't want to use the cursorAt option in order to solve this...

Thanks ahead,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I solved it by modifying the the `.colum` class `padding-bottom:` from  `100px` into `300px`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand the question, but I think you want to be able to drag the portlets by their headers only (therefor, the center of the "drag" will be the header's center).
If so, you can add

```
handle: ".portlet-header"
```

to your sortable options.

```
$(".column").sortable({
        connectWith : ".column",
        handle: ".portlet-header"
    });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3LKj4/1/

Comment: That's not what i've meant, i want to be able to drag the portlet by holding it no matter where - even by holding its footer/center , and get the place holder to be displayed as if i was holding the portlet header , look how it behaves when you drag the portlet by holding it in the center or the footer...

Comment: JsFiddle link is broken :(